# the submit button is not working

Tags: php, html, wordpress, button, submit

I am new web-designer and made my contact page with Dreamweaver. When I upload my blog the submit button is not working and the technical support in WordPress says I should edit the blank code in html page. Can somebody help me with that? 
Here is my HTML page( contact.html):

```
     <td width="49%" height="336" align="left" valign="middle">
     <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action=" wp-includes/pluggable.php">
     <p>
       <label for="name">Name</label>
       <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
     </p>
     <p>&nbsp;</p>
     <p>
       <label for="email">Email</label>
       <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
       </p>
     <p><br />
       Comment<br />
       <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
       </p>
     <p>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
       <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
     </p>
   </form></td>
```

and here is  my php page: (wp-includes/pluggable.php) I just entered my email address there:

```
// From email and name
// If we don't have a name from the input headers
if ( !isset( $from_name ) )
    $from_name = 'WordPress';

/* If we don't have an email from the input headers default to wordpress@$sitename
 * Some hosts will block outgoing mail from this address if it doesn't exist but
 * there's no easy alternative. Defaulting to admin_email might appear to be another
 * option but some hosts may refuse to relay mail from an unknown domain. See
 * http://trac.wordpress.org/ticket/5007.
 */

if ( !isset( $from_email ) ) {
    // Get the site domain and get rid of www.
    $sitename = strtolower( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] );
    if ( substr( $sitename, 0, 4 ) == 'www.' ) {
        $sitename = substr( $sitename, 4 );
    }

    $from_email = 'some_email@somewhere.com' . $sitename;
}
```

Comment: Is this your full/entire code?

Comment: And `not working` implies?

Comment: You're not opening and closing with braces `{ }` for your `if ( !isset( $from_name ) )` for one thing.

Comment: 2. `$from_email = 'mitneh@gmail.com' . $sitename;` should be `$from_email = 'mitneh@' . $sitename;`

Comment: Suggestion: Mitra, if Dreamweaver's giving you a hard time, Google `email form plugin wordpress` or check this one with a rather high rating http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/

Comment: thanks for your answers.not working means goes to a blank page.

Comment: Dear fred this codes were written by wordpress in php. I did not write them.thats why I did not add braces to them.

Comment: @MitraNehchiri I understand. I suggest again that you look into "working codes" and test/learn with them. Once you have working code, you can customize later on, once you get a basic `understanding`. Nobody said it was going to be easy. Learning, is a good thing and so is failing; success is the icing on the cake. ;)

Comment: thanks  fred. I am a student and supposed to learn to work with dreamweaver. it is not my complete code page. it is very long. thanks again

Comment: @MitraNehchiri Anytime Mitra. Dreamweaver is but `one tool`. Personally, I `hand/hard code` everything. I won't have software to blame but myself if something goes wrong, I just have to go back to `the source` ;) cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try Removing the space in your form action from:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action=" wp-includes/pluggable.php">
```

Should be this:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="wp-includes/pluggable.php">
```

Comment: Yeah, spaces are murder (at times)